# Django: Multiple login redirects based on path

Tags: python, django

I have the following two urls:

```
url(r'^login/$',django.contrib.auth.views.login,{'template_name': 'meta/login.html'},name='login'),
url(r'^loginiOS/$', django.contrib.auth.views.login, {'template_name': 'meta/login.html'}, name='loginiOS'),
```

They load the login page but the "loginiOS" URL allows me to hide certain options on the iPhone version such as the menu.  An example can be seen below:

```
  {% if 'iOS' in request.path %}
  {% else %}
    {% include "meta/fragments/navbar.html" %}
    {% block header %}{% endblock %}
  {% endif %}
```

However, whenever I login it always redirects me to "https://str8red.com/welcome" which is set in the settings file.  What I would like to do is have the login page redirect as follows:

- If its from str8red.com/login then redirect to stre8red.com/welcome
- If its from str8red.com/loginiOS then redirect to str8red.com/welcomeiOS

I have tried a few ideas out and had a look on stackoverflow without success.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Many thanks, Alan.

Comment: you can match it with either parameter or by reverse match url whatever you prefer

Comment: Sorry, could you elaborate on one of the two suggested solutions please as I am unclear on how to execute your suggestion.

Comment: override `django.contrib.auth.views.login`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want user to be redirected to certain page after successful login, you can add `next` param to form. Something like:

```html
<form>
  {% if 'iOS' in request.path %}
    <input type="hidden" name="next" value="iosUrl" />
  {% endif %}
</form>
```

Comment: Hit the nail on the head, thank you.  Many thanks to others that also offered up suggestions.

Comment: Hello ookami.kb, I tried something similar with the change password option but it did not work.  If you have any thoughts please could you help here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45176991/django-redirect-change-password-url.