# Django: Redirect Change Password URL

Tags: django, django-forms

I have the following two URLs:

```
url(r'^change-password/$',django.contrib.auth.views.password_change,{'template_name': 'meta/changepassword.html', 'post_change_redirect': '/password-changed/'},name='change_password'),
url(r'^change-passwordiOS/$',django.contrib.auth.views.password_change,{'template_name': 'meta/changepassword.html', 'post_change_redirect': '/password-changed/'},name='change_passwordiOS'),
```

I thought if I used the following within the change password form it would override what URL would be loaded:

```
        {% if 'iOS' in request.path %}
          <input type="hidden" name="next" value="/profileiOS/" />
        {% endif %}
```

But when I reach the change password from the `url(r'^change-passwordiOS/$'` and click the "Change Button" it does not goto the /profileiOS/ as expected but the standard /profile/ URL.

Any help would be appreciated.

/change-password/ view:

```
@login_required
def password_changed(request):
    messages.success(request, 'Your password has been changed.')
    return redirect(reverse('profile'))
```

Full Change Password Form:

```
      <form class="form-horizontal" role="form" method="post" action="">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <fieldset>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label class="col-md-6 control-label">{{ form.old_password.label }}:</label>
            <div class="col-md-6">
              <input name="old_password" type="password" class="form-control"/>
              <div class="text-danger">
                {% for error in form.old_password.errors %}{{ error }}<br/>{% endfor %}
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label class="col-md-6 control-label">{{ form.new_password1.label }}:</label>
            <div class="col-md-6">
              <input name="new_password1" type="password" class="form-control"/>
              <div class="text-danger">
                {% for error in form.new_password1.errors %}{{ error }}<br/>{% endfor %}
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label class="col-md-6 control-label">{{ form.new_password2.label }}:</label>
            <div class="col-md-6">
              <input name="new_password2" type="password" class="form-control"/>
              <div class="text-danger">
                {% for error in form.new_password2.errors %}{{ error }}<br/>{% endfor %}
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <div class="text-right col-sm-12">
              <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Change Password^</button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </fieldset>
        {% if 'iOS' in request.path %}
          <input type="hidden" name="next" value="/profileiOS/" />
        {% endif %}
      </form>
```

Comment: Are you sure it is redirecting you to `/profile/` page? From you code it should rather go to `/password-changed/`.

Comment: I thought that but it is going to /profile/ :/ . Added the view for /password-changed/ to the question which explains it.  Sorry for slow reply.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are manually redirecting to `/profile/` in `password_changed` view. You can change your redirect logic to depend on post param from template:

```
@login_required
def password_changed(request):
  messages.success(request, 'Your password has been changed.')
  return redirect(request.POST.get('next', reverse('profile')))
```